# how to make an easy register of different classes in c# with readline?

Tags: c#

I was given an assignment thats about to save data for name, age and weight for all animals.

- For the cows he also wants to save how many liters of milk each cow yields per year and what percentage of the milk contains.
- For the sheep, he wants to save how many kilos you get per year and what color you have.
- For dogs, Allan wants to save the name of the feed that the dog eats.

Create a simple registry that can save data about animals. Add animals of every variety to the registry.

Create a method for each type of animal that prints: For the cows: Name, Age Weight, LiterOfMilk, PercentOfCream.
For the sheep: Name, Age Weight, Kilowool, woolColor 
For the dogs: Name, Age Weight, FoodName

Also create a method that counts which is the oldest animal.´

All i did for now is to create classes like this:

```
public class Cow
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //...and so on
}
```

but i dont really knows how to do it in best way.. at this point I think that you figur it out that I'm noob at this, so try to be kind :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a page to solve your homework. Read about polymorphism and List<T>

Comment: I should probably explain that all i need is a "leading" not solving the problem :D just "show me the door and let me in". but thx, i'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrays to save data about the animals:

```
/*something like*/ Cow[15] cows = new Cow[];
```

You can iterate through each cow to search the oldest one, and so on.

To create Main class Animal from which each animal will derive

```
Public class Animal { //...code}
```

To show information about individual animal I would suggest override ToString() method:

```
Public class Cow : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name/*+ other properties*/;
    }
}
```

Happy coding ;)